# How Do I Pass One List From A Class To Another Class?

Tags: python

I am new to using multiple classes in python and I am trying to create a Stock class that holds all the data for a single stock. However, when I try to do the basic initialization of the Stock class, the data variable registers as having no data. How do I fix this, and what am I doing wrong?

Class one

```
import Stock

stock = Stock.Stock("MSFT")

print(stock.data)
```

Class two

```
class Stock():

  data = []

  def __init__(self, ticker):
    self.ticker = ticker

    from yahoo_historical import Fetcher
    chart = Fetcher(ticker, [2019, 1, 1], [2019, 6, 1])
    data = chart.getHistorical()
```

Output: []

Comment: Within a class method, you need to prefix all instance variables with `self.`  Otherwise they're just local variables that go out of scope when the method returns.

Comment: Wow, kicking myself for that. Thanks!

Comment: And the variables instantiated inside a class but outside class methods are all class variables rather than instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `data = chart.getHistorical()` you are creating a new local variable, not setting that variable `data = []` over there.

You need to scope to `self` so doing `self.data = chart.getHistorical()` would suffice for your problem.

Also note that using lists as class variables are danger. When you do

```
class Foo:
   bar = []
```

And then

```
foo1 = Foo()
foo2 = Foo()
foo1.bar.append('Hello from foo1')
print(foo2.bar)
```

You would expect that this would print `[]` but will print `['Hello from foo1']`. The problem here os that both instances have a property `bar` pointing to the same array object, when you modify this object both see the modification. For you case you can just drop the `data = []` at class scope and keep with the `self.data = ...` at method scope

I hope that this helps